# How can I create a dropdown list which depends on the text entered into a form field?

Tags: php, dropdown

I have records in a table called baymatrix:
Location, Description
examples:
UW-01-03-04-XX, Yamaha Secondary Clutch
UW-01-03-03-XX, Polaris Secondary Clutch
UW-01-03-02-XX, Arctic Cat Secondary Clutch
UW-01-03-01-XX, Bombardier Secondary Clutch

I want a user to enter search text (description field, ignoring case), and on the same page, a select dropdown is populated with the results (Location fields corresponding to records which contain the search text in the description field of "baymatrix").

Example, if the user types "yamaha" into the search field, he/she would see one option in the dropdown.
If he types "clutch", he would see four in the dropdown, and so on....

Please help!
Mark

Comment: Google for "autocomplete". There are plenty solutions.

Comment: Is that autocomplete / auto suggestion?